# Send Request from my android application and get request from another application?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I'm developing two android applications. Now I want to send 'Hello' string from my first App to my second App. My second application have to receive that 'Hello' string and concatenate ' world'  and have to response as 'Hello world'.

After that I want to Toast as a string 'Hello world' from my first App. How can we achieve this using Android service?

Comment: You can use the Bind service using messenger or AIDL.   https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Answer (score 0):

[ContentProviders](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) (see full description) are a good approach to share data between applications.